# Что нужно знать тестировщику ПО (QA)

Tags: работа, тестирование

Много ли нужно знать, чтобы устроиться тестировщиком ПО?
На первый взгляд, всё довольно просто, но если бы всё было так просто, тогда многие бы были тестировщиками ПО и получали за это нормальные деньги!
Что реально делает этот человек и сколько этому нужно учиться?

Comment: свое место :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

начали бы объяснять, что есть 2 типа тестирования: программное - написание автоматических тестов, скрипты, алгоритмы, гуглить по слову selenium (платят больше чем), ручное - проклацивать кнопочки и говорить, что рамочка в ие поползла ( гуглить по monkey work :) ).

учится на такое - лучше на курсах компании, которая набирает себе в штат, они расскажут требования, покажут куда нажимать, примеры, советы

Answer (score 3):

Вообще то QA и тестировщики - это немного разные специальности. Некоторые в этом видят очень принципиальную разницу и сильно обижаются, если их называют неправильно. (QA говорит, что они не тестируют, а проверяют качество. Но чем это отличается - не знаю.)

**на первый взгляд**

Обычно работа тестировщика достаточно проста - написали программисты "добавили мега фичу", значит нужно проверить, как именно она работает, а не сломали ли старые фичи и не откатили ли старые баги (регресивный анализ).

Но это на первый взгляд. По факту, иногда работа качественного тестировщика может быть сложнее программиста. Некоторые тестировщики пишут автоматизированные тесты для проверки работы программы (не путать с юниттестированием). Составляют детальные планы проверок.

**тестеры всякие нужны, тестеры всякие важны**

Следующий этап - это узнать, что тестеры бывают разные. Есть тестеры интерфейсов. Они могут выставить нестандартную тему для людей с слабым зрением и смотреть, а все ли кнопки видимы. А все ли можно нажать, если использовать только одну мышку или клавиатуру. А если переключить интерфейс на китайский или иврит, то все нормально отображается?

**где учат на тестеров?**

Я считаю, что на нормального тестера, как и на нормального программиста, выучиться нельзя. Можно научиться многим приемам, знать все методики тестирования, но все равно не замечать серьезных багов и просчетов.

Я лично знаю двоих тестеров, которые точно на это не учились (у одного из них даже нет полного высшего образования). Но это абсолютно не мешает находить такие баги, о которых бы и не подумал.

Comment: QA следит за процессом в принципе (если вкратце), не только за багами.

Comment: Это уже будут менеджеры.

Comment: Проработал 2 месяца тестировщиком. Поначалу действительно казалось, что платят хорошие деньги ни за что (тем более, что стажером был и на втором курсе учусь сейчас), но потом начался мой субъективный ад - много рутинной работы, регрессии тоже порядочно. Одно радовало - отводилось время на написание автотестов. По поводу учёбы - давали в первый месяц работы изучить курс стратоплан по тестированию, там наверное много занятных вещей (мне, субъективно, все эти статьи и курсы по тестированию напоминают фразу "из пустого в порожнее"), но я все-таки думаю, что только практика действительно научит

Comment: @KoVadim, как бы менеджеры, которые разбираются в проектировании и коде. У меня во всяком случае сложилось такое мнение. 
Тестировщик - это такой технический гуманитарий.

Comment: А реально мы занимались: подготовка тестовых данных (самая долгое и скучное занятие), написание чек-листов (вначале пишешь как, что, с какими параметрами будешь проводить тестирование (чтобы потом отчитаться четко можно было)), писали тест-кейсы (порой очень сложно правильно выразить мысль, творческий процесс), планировали - тоже сложно, тем более новичку, понять сколько времени займет задача. Но самое сложное - было создать видимость работы :)

Comment: @Veikedo

>> как бы менеджеры, которые разбираются в проектировании и коде

Вот таких нужно гнать сразу. Честно. зачем целый отдел "как бы менеджеров".

Comment: @KoVadim, скажем так: неплохие управленцы получаются и из технарей, которые знакомы с производством изнутри. Так у них хватает же ума не лезть в тот самый процесс :) Но управленец, который "знаком" (особенно прочитав пару книжек уровня 'XXX для чайников') и суёт свой нос в техдетали производства - это да, нет ничего хуже :(

Answer (score 2):

Добавил бы ещё к ответу [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim).

1) Грамотность, ясность мысли, умение обозначить проблему и донести её до разработчика. "У вас тут ни черта не работает" - это не тестер! Выяви условия её проявления, распиши всё по пунктам, чтобы разработчик не бегал потом к тебе с вопросами типа "покажи, как ты это уронил?". Для этого нужно обладать неплохой технической эрудицией как минимум.

2) Работа с техдокументацией, багтрекером, реквест-трекером и т.д. См. пункт 1: документирование проблемы должно быть максимально подробным, но без излишеств. Хорошее знание тестируемого продукта, чтобы понимать: какие проблемы куда относить (разработчиков много, каждый отвечает за своё, проект, как правило, разбит на подзадачи), какие задачи объединять, какие наоборот, разбивать на более мелкие. Идеальный случай - когда разработчики и тестеры вообще не пересекаются лично, вся работа идёт только через тикеты, и при этом всем всё понятно.

3) Вытекающее из знания продукта: умение расставлять приоритеты. Чтобы не орать на всю контору про мелкие интерфейсные недочёты или выставлить хай приорити задачам, которые накануне релиза решать никто не будет. Информационный шум только отвлекает. А вот выявить потенциальную проблему, которая может серьёзно на что-то повлиять - молодчина!

Может ещё что вспомню :)

Про написание автоматических тестов. Можно, например, решать такие задачи: разворачивание дистрибутивов/инсталляторов на разных системах в разных условиях (обновление пред. версий, установка с нуля, изменение юзером опций в инсталляторе etc). Задача сама по себе нехилая, и требует внимательного подхода к учёту (автоматизированому!) всех мелочей...

Comment: Вот интереса ради, заглянул в "вакансии" родной компании. На самом деле я там уже не работаю, но проработал 10 лет, и контактов не прерываю, так что до сих пор родная :) Рядовой тестер для Unix-линейки. Из спецтребований - самые обычные, хотя казалось бы:

* Хорошее знание UNIX систем (Linux, BSD, Solaris);

* Знание почтовых систем (Sendmail, Postfix, Exim, Qmail, CGP), Samba, Squid;

Ну, то есть, в "окружении", в котором работает программа, нужно ориентироваться на очень хорошем уровне, как ни крути.